# Is there a way to change IIS bindings without recycling the application pool?

Tags: windows, iis-7

Is there a way to make IIS start or stop listening on a port, without recycling the application pool? For example, I have a reverse proxy listening on port 80 and passing requests to my site on 8080. However in case there is a problem with the reverse proxy, I need to be able to turn it off have my IIS site listen on port 80.

My site has to load a lot of reference data at startup, and I need a way to change the IIS settings on the fly without losing the loaded data.

I've tried the IIS manager, and I've tried using AppCmd.exe, both caused a recycle.
This is on IIS 7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope.  Any changes will cause an app pool recycle.  I'd look at reworking the site so it doesn't have to load so much data at startup.